# Should I make my Haskell modules Safe by default?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there any downside to marking the modules `Safe`? Should it be the assumed default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can read in the [GHC user manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/safe_haskell.html#safe-language), if you mark your modules `Safe`, you are restricted to a certain "safe" subset of the Haskell language.

1. You can only import modules which are also marked `Safe` (which rules out functions like `unsafeCoerce` or `unsafePerformIO`).
2. You can't use Template Haskell.
3. You can't use FFI outside of `IO`.
4. You can't use `GeneralisedNewtypeDeriving`.
5. You can't manually implement the `Generic` typeclass for the types you define in your module.
6. etc.

In exchange, the users of the module gain a bunch of guarantees (quoting from the manual):

> - Referential transparency — The types can be trusted. Any pure function, is guaranteed to be pure. Evaluating them is deterministic
>     and won’t cause any side effects. Functions in the `IO` monad are still
>     allowed and behave as usual. So, for example, the `unsafePerformIO ::
>     IO a -> a` function is disallowed in the safe language to enforce this
>     property.
> - Module boundary control — Only symbols that are publicly available through other module export lists can be accessed in the safe
>     language. Values using data constructors not exported by the defining
>     module, cannot be examined or created. As such, if a module `M`
>     establishes some invariants through careful use of its export list,
>     then code written in the safe language that imports `M` is guaranteed to
>     respect those invariants.
> - Semantic consistency — For any module that imports a module written in the safe language, expressions that compile both with and without
>     the safe import have the same meaning in both cases. That is,
>     importing a module written in the safe language cannot change the
>     meaning of existing code that isn’t dependent on that module. So, for
>     example, there are some restrictions placed on the use of
>     `OverlappingInstances`, as these can violate this property.
> - Strict subset — The safe language is strictly a subset of Haskell as implemented by GHC. Any expression that compiles in the safe language
>     has the same meaning as it does when compiled in normal Haskell.

Note that safety is inferred. If your module is not marked with any of `Safe`, `Trustworthy`, or `Unsafe`, GHC will infer the safety of the module to `Safe` or `Unsafe`. When you set the `Safe` flag, then GHC will issue an error if it decides the module is not actually safe. You can also set `-Wunsafe`, which emits a warning if a module is inferred to be unsafe. If you let it be inferred, your module will continue to compile even if your dependencies' safety statuses change. If you write it out, you promise to your users that the safety status is stable and dependable.

One use case described in the manual refers to running "untrusted" code. If you provide extension points of any kind in your product and you want to make sure that those capabilities aren't used to attack your product, you can require the code for the extension points to be marked `Safe`.

You can mark your module `Trustworthy` and this doesn't restrict you in any way while implementing your module. Your module might be used from `Safe` code then and it is your responsibility to not violate the guaranties, that should be given by `Safe` code. So this is a promise, you the author of said module, give. You can use the flag `-fpackage-trust` to enable extra checks while compiling modules marked as `Trustworthy` described [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/safe_haskell.html#safe-trust).

So, if you write normal libraries and don't have a good reason to care about Safe Haskell, then you probably shouldn't care. If your modules are safe, thats fine and can be inferred. If not, then this is probably for a reason, like because you used `unsafePerformIO`, which is also fine. If you know your module will be used in a way that requires it to compile under `-XSafe` (e.g. plugins, as above), you should do it. In all other cases, don't bother.

Comment: The #1 blocker is Template Haskell for me, actually. Unfortunately it also prevents the use of `makeLenses`. We can only hope this restriction gets lifted someday.

Comment: It can't be lifted, without giving up on the guaranty that a safe module can only use symbols other modules willingly exported. TH can be used to circumvent that, the ghc manual claims. (I am not a TH user much and doesn't know, how that "circumvention" would work.)

Comment: I've edited the answer for clarity, but I'd like to add (and I didn't edit this in because I think it's a substantial change in meaning) that, while letting `Safe` and `Unsafe` be inferred is usually fine, some libraries should declare themselves `Trustworthy`. When used in a library, `Safe` and `Unsafe` mean "the API exported by this module is safe/unsafe." `Trustworthy` means "the API exported is safe, but the implementation isn't." A library may not directly be used in a `Safe` context, but its users might be, so it should be nice and mark its safe API as such to let those users use it.

Comment: @HTNW: Your right, I should add this. Will do, when I am back from work.